# Can't Edit a Post after completing Suggested Edits Review Queue

Tags: discussion, support, bug

I had completed my reviews for Suggested Edits and reviewing Late Answers Queue, where I see an Answer which needs to be correctly formatted. So I click on edit, as there a pending review for Suggested Edit I was redirected to the UI of Suggested Edits without any action buttons (because I already reached a limit of 20). I know that post will be improved by someone from the community but I want to know that

- Is there any other option/button where I can edit the post
- Or directly open the edit option (as we have for regular edits
  without any pending edits) for the users with a reputation of 2000 or
  more as this might be a conflict with ([edit privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)) or I am missing something

[Post which was needed an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53458369/typeerror-value-parameter-must-be-a-scalar-dict-or-series-but-you-passed-a/57178327#57178327)

from Late Answer Queque
[image: Image from Late Answer Queque]

Redirected to Suggested Edits Queque
[image: Redireted to Suggested Edits Queque]